# JavaFx numberbind and TextField

Tags: javafx

I want to subtract a variable `totalAmount` which is a `IntegerBind` and a Value from a `TextField`

I know this kind of syntax won't be valid because they're not compatible a parse `TextField`  and a `IntegerBind` identifier.

```
int parseReceivedCash = Integer.parseInt(receivedCashTextField.getText());

if((parseReceivedCash - alltotal))
{
  Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
  alert.setHeaderText("Not Enough Cas");
  alert.setContentText("Sorry not enough cash"  );
  alert.showAndWait();
}


alltotal = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> 
    tableData.getItems().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Data::getSubTotal)),
    tableData.getItems());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
IntegerProperty receivedCash = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
receivedCashTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(receivedCash, new NumberStringConverter());
IntegerBinding remainingAmount = allTotal.subtract(receivedCash);

remainingAmount.addListener(...); // check if amount is enough, etc...
```

should provide the functionality you are looking for

Comment: can i do this using the textfield receivedCash and add some addlisteners to it ?

Comment: Why would you want to add listener to `receivedCash`?

Comment: well i mean the textfield receivedCash , it will subtract the alltotal integerbind when i input some value on it . but it will be impossible for the textfield and the integerbind